# Loading of UIView crashing

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview

Whenever I try to do anything with a certain UIView my program crashes:

```
chatRoomInputView.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
```

I've tried to do this in the viewDidLoad and in the viewDidAppear.
I double checked and everything is properly connected in the interface builder.

The program crashes with the message:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Comment: Have you implement `init` method in `ChatRoomMessageInputViewController`

Comment: It contains "required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }"

Comment: Check if `chatRoomInputView` exists. You should have an nil object in that assignment.

Comment: You are correct. It is also crashing on just the line:         self.chatRoomInputView.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()

Comment: Is the `self.chatRoomInputView`the problem so?

Comment: yep, i don't understand why though?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `if let` statement:

```
if let view = chatRoomInputView {
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
}
```

... if your `chatRoomInputView?` variable is optional